# duplicate sonarqube checkstyle rules

Tags: sonarqube, checkstyle

is there a possibility to duplicate existing checkstyle rules? I want Sonarqube to differ guideline rules.

Example:

The rule for method complexity should mark the method as [MINOR] when there is more than 10 lines of code per method and as [MAJOR] when there is more than 30 lines of code per method.

Maybe there is a particular plugin for this special case?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently a limitation in SonarQube. However, it can be done partially.

For Checkstyle based rules, you can copy *some* rules (those that have a *Copy Rule* button; [screenshot here](http://www.sonarqube.org/sonar-2-3-in-screenshots/) under "Multiple activation of rules"). I've personally used this for the Comment Pattern Matcher and created a rule that matches TODO comments as INFO severity and another that matches FIXME comments as CRITICAL. As I understand your question, that is what you are looking for. I don't think this is possible for *all* parameterizable rules, though.

Also, for PMD based rules, there is [this blog post](http://refaktor.blogspot.de/2013/12/custom-sonarqube-rules-for-unit-tests.html) which describes how to use the XPath rule template in order to create custom PMD rules. This could be a workaround for those PMD based rules that don't have a *Copy Rule* button.

The feature we would need is a *Copy Rule* button for every parameterizable rule. AFAIK, this does not exist yet.

Comment: Thanks. Thats exactly what i was asking about. I guess there is a chance to duplicate the rule in the database but the effort is to much to handle it for lots of rules.